# rewriting a substring of a filename in RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use the .htaccess code to have different pages loaded when mobile user-agent recognized.

It doesn't work but I can't figure why, can someone please help?

The below RewriteConds work for me when followed by the RewriteRule for redirecting to subdomain, so I guess there must be a problem with my RewriteRules.

Help appreciated.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ (ce|phone)|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]

RewriteRule ^regular.css$ mobi.css
RewriteRule ^view.$ mobile.view.
```

Answer (score 1):

You writing `^view.$` supposes that you think of a file named "view." (it's the *complete* filename, ending with a dot). Is that really what you mean?

`$` marks the end (of the original string the regex is being matched against). Perhaps, you don't need it.

(Read docs about regexes before you use them in order to understand every symbol you write! Writing code and not understanding what it means is not nice.)

#### Further problems

I see, after you get rid of the `$`, you might get further problems, because you might want to construct a complete filename on the right-hand side of the rewrite-rule (like something that eveluates to "mobile.view.mainlayout.php") (or not?).

I don't remember: does Apache's rewrite-rules rewrite only the small matched piece ("view.") in the string and concatenate it with the rest of the requested filename ("mainlayout.php"), or Apache throws away the old requested filename ("view.mainlayout.php") and replaces it with what it finds on the right-hand side of the rewrite-rule (so it must be not a replacing piece like "mobile.view.", but rather evaluate to a complete filename)?

If so, then match the rest of the string with `( )` in the regex on the left-hand side of the rewrite-rule, and insert the matched piece back on the right-hand side.

Comment: Actually, it's sort of MVC, so my filenames are like:   view.mainlayout.php     and mobile version is:  mobile.view.mainlayout.php     I think you can see where I'm trying to get with this, can I do it? Or only the entire filename can be rewritten?

Comment: In my answer, **"you don't need it"** means **"you dont' need $"** .

Answer (score 1):

Main problem is that you cannot have multiple RewriteRules after RewriteConds, so your second RewriteRule will be executed every time.

You have to do a little workaround with the `skip` flag, see below.

Note: The RewriteConds are 'inverted'.

The second problem is your RegEx: `RewriteRule ^view.$ mobile.view.` just rewrites the URL `view (followed by one random char)` to the URL `mobile.view.`.

As I noticed in your comment, you have to do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^view\.(.*)$ mobile.view.$1  # files and .htaccess have to be in the same directory
```

Here the full Rewrite code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ (ce|phone)|xda|xiino [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [S=2]  # skip next two RewriteRules if RewriteConds matched (= it's a desktop browser)
RewriteRule ^regular.css$ mobi.css
RewriteRule ^view\.(.*)$ mobile.view.$1
```

Comment: First of all, Freelancer has to learn and understand something like the common regex syntax. In order to understand what is meant by the symbols he/she types: `$`, `.`, `( )`... That's not that difficult. But will the ready full code be an incentive for him/her to think and learn?

Comment: thanks, I think I understand the code, but it's not working for me, any idea why?

Comment: @imz: +1 for one of the most annoying and most VALUABLE advices I got. In the end it came down to exactly that, rolling up my sleeves and getting full grasp of the thing.

Comment: @Freelancer: Thanks for the kind words! ;) I'm glad you were finally able to write up a working solution. I'm a bit curious about what you had to improve. Would mind posting here the solution you have found for your task with some brief explanations about what turned out to be important? That would make this page more valuable and interesting. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

@Freelancer [Edited to fix errors and provide alternative]

You want a `[PT]` on your `RewriteRule` statements.

Skipping is probably your best bet:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" "!(first-condition-regex)"  [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" "!(second-condition-regex)" [NC]
RewriteRule "^"                "-"                            [SKIP=2]
RewriteRule "^regular.css$"    "mobi.css"                    [PT]
RewriteRule "^(view\..*)"      "mobile.$1"                   [PT]
```

If you want to avoid inverting your conditions it gets a bit messier:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" "first-condition-regex"  [OR,NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" "second-condition-regex" [NC]
RewriteRule "^"                   "-"                      [E=MOBILE:TRUE]
RewriteCond "%{ENV:MOBILE}"       "!=TRUE"
RewriteRule "^"                   "-"                      [SKIP=2]
RewriteRule "^regular.css$"       "mobi.css"              [PT]
RewriteRule "^(view\..*)"         "mobile.$1"             [PT]
```

As pointed out, all these files need to be in the same directory as the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Yeah, I made a stupid error.  Take a look at the modified answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help, still couldn't make it work, it's definitely me doing something wrong.